# Trying to understand recursion in python code

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to understand this code which uses recursion to find the maximum path in a binary tree:

```
 def maxPathSum(self, root):
    def dfs(node):  # returns: max one side path sum, max path sum
        l = r = 0
        ls = rs = None
        if node.left:
            l, ls = dfs(node.left)
            l = max(l, 0)
        if node.right:
            r, rs = dfs(node.right)
            r = max(r, 0)
        return node.val + max(l, r), max(node.val + l + r, ls, rs)
    if root:
        return dfs(root)[1]
    return 0
```

I don't understand how this will find the maximum path. When it calls itself recursively, it keeps resetting  `l` and `r` to 0 and `ls` and `rs` to `None`.

EDIT:

As suggested, I tested it on a simple binary tree with 5 as the root with LC: 2 and RC:3 and node 3 also has a LC: 4.

I got these results: (printed after the `l = max(l, 0)` and `r = max(r, 0)` lines:

iteration1: l = 2, ls = 2, r= 0, rs = None

iteration2: l = 4, ls = 4, r = 0, rs = None

iteration3: l=2, ls =2, r = 7, rs = 7

Somehow from this---it manages to get max one side sum as 12 and max path sum as 14 (which is correct). Even after playing with the numbers, I don't understand how the code arrive to the answers.

Also what is the point of this part of the code: `l = max(l, 0)`--I removed it and the answer remains the same?

Source: https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/27059/12-lines-of-python-code-fast-and-easy-to-understand

Comment: `l`, `r`, `ls`, and `rs` only have scope within (a given iteration of) the function `dfs`.

Comment: Here's a useful tool for visualizing recurcive functions http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: I am still not understand how this code works. For example, why do we need both `l`, `r` and `ls` and `rs`?

Comment: Hint: `dfs` is short for **depth-first search**. What is done to `ls` that's different from what's done to `l`? Incidentally, this is a good illustration of why `l`, `ls`, etc, are **terrible** names for variables.

Comment: What have you done so far to trace the operation of the code?  I can't demonstrate, since you haven't included enough to run the code.

Comment: @Prune: I think the code is recursively grabbing all the values for the left child and for the right child of the tree then finding the max sum of the left and right. What I am confused is picturing how it works....so it recursively grabs the left child of the current node, but it is finding the max of that left child, instead of the max of the left child and its parent nodes. For some reason, I just have a hard time picturing how this code works.

Comment: Create a simple example of a (labeled) binary tree, and follow the code line by line to see what it does. Use a debugger, `print` statements, or even write everything out by hand on paper.

Comment: @vanillabee: that's good so far, but doesn't address either of my concerns.  I'm trying to lead you into learning how to (1) examine a program, and (2) post good questions.

Comment: As an exercise, what _would_ be good names for the variables? Obviously, as @jack-maney has said, the dfs() function should be renamed something like depth_first_search(), and just for clarity's sake node.val works well as node.value. So what would you name l, r, ls and rs? This may seem silly, but I find that thinking these things through and writing them out sometimes unlocks mental blocks I wasn't aware I had.

Comment: I understand dfs and I understand what the code is attempting to do BUT I just can't understand how the recursion is working in this code....I also don't understand why no one can explain it clearly instead of giving some vague tips. I did all the testing and printing on my own yesterday and spent hours on this one problem but I am still confused on how the recursion works in this particular code :(

Comment: @vanillabee I understand your frustration. I think one reason people are leading rather than directly answering is that they've all been through this, and found that having it explained clearly the first time just didn't stick. I think it's one of those things folks find frustrating until they've beaten their heads against it for long enough.